# How to determine whether a TSysCharSet (set of AnsiChar) is unassigned?

Tags: delphi

In order to avoid possible error in a function, I need to precheck whether a variable of type **TSysCharSet** (or **set of AnsiChar**) is unassigned. How can I do it?

```pascal
procedure TestSysCharSet(const AnsiCharSet: TSysCharSet);
begin
  if PByte(@AnsiCharSet) = nil then WriteLn('The AnsiCharSet is unassigned.')
  else if AnsiCharSet = [] then WriteLn('The AnsiCharSet is empty.');
end;

procedure Test();
var
  AnsiCharSet: TSysCharSet;

begin
  // The AnsiCharSet is intentionally made unassigned
  TestSysCharSet(AnsiCharSet);
  ReadLn;
end;

begin
  Test();
end.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have edited the code sample.

Comment: You cannot. That variable can have "any value" at that moment.

Comment: You can't "unassign" a set. But you can make a set empty (`[]`), as you already know. Delphi does not have nullable types (yet -- they were announced for a later version in the latest roadmap, IIRC).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no possible way to detect this. This is an unmanaged value type and when declared as a local variable it is not initialised. It will have a value, but that value is undefined and indistinguishable from any other value.

Note that this is not special to this type. The same argument applies to other such types, for example `Integer`, `Boolean`, `Double`, etc.